# IntelliTest on Xamarin or VS on Mac?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, intellitest

Is intellitest available on Xamarin or VS for Mac? I have business level subscription for Xamarin? Or is it only on VS on pc. If yes, do we need any subsciption?

Comment: Do we need to have any subscription level or is it available even for community version ?

Comment: Intellitest is currently a Visual Studio **Enterprise** (Windows) feature only.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not supported. I have created a uservoice item here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/17379676-enable-intellitest-in-visual-studio-on-mac. Please consider voting.